# How to fix ''System.ArgumentException" in c#?

Tags: c#, codedom

I'm working on a small project that involves compiling code. I keep getting this error: An unhandled exception of type `System.ArgumentException` occurred in mscorlib.dll Illegal characters in path.

I've tried finding the source of the problem, this line of code seems to be the problem:

```
CompilerResults cr = provider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(parameters, source1);
```

This is my code for my class:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;

namespace Plugin___Prototype
{
    class CompileCode
    {
        public void Compile()
        {
            string source1 = File.ReadAllText(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + @"\test.cs");
            //string source2 = File.ReadAllText(@"Source path here");
            Console.WriteLine(source1);
            CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
            CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
            parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
            parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
            parameters.OutputAssembly = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + @"\app1.exe";
            Console.WriteLine(parameters.OutputAssembly);
            parameters.GenerateInMemory = false;
            CompilerResults cr = provider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(parameters, source1);

            if (cr.Errors.Count == 0)
                Console.WriteLine("No Errors");
            else
            {
                foreach (CompilerError error in cr.Errors)
                    Console.WriteLine(error.ErrorText);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Illegal characters in path.

The program '[14128] Plugin - Prototype.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

My expected result is for app1.exe to generated in my documents folder.

EDIT: These are the contents of source1:

```
// A Hello World! program in C#.
using System;
namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Hello
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the contents of `string source1` ? Check that

Comment: Check the edit i added.

Comment: You need to evaluate the _error message_ associated with that exception, not (necessarily) the exception itself. The message tells you `Illegal characters in path.`. So you've got an issue with the value of the path you are trying to use.

Comment: Try splitting the first operation into 2 parts. Generating the path, and a second part to read the text from the file. Also, use [Path.Combine()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.8) instead of string concatenation to generate the path: `string path = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "test.cs"); string source1 = File.ReadAllText(path);` Now you can use the debugger to see what the value of `path` is, etc. to figure out what's actually wrong.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the section in a try/catch and viewing the stack trace of the exception to see exactly where it is being thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed it, `CompilerResults cr = provider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(parameters, source1);`, wanted the file not the contents of the file.

Comment: One take away is: Indicating which line is generating the exception is helpful when asking a question of this nature.

Answer (score 1):

If someone else is having the same error but the above fix did not work for you, then you may need to check the contents of your secrets file for spelling errors, trust server, and that your password matches your server.